# Regular expression search and substitute values in CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, search, substitution

I want to find and replace all of the Managerial positions in a CSV file with number 3. The list contains different positions from simple ",Manager," to ",Construction Project Manager and Project Superintendent," but all of them are placed between two commas. I wrote this to find them all:

```
[,\s]?([A-Za-z. '\s/()\"]+)?(Manager|manager)([A-Za-z. '\s/()]+)?,
```

The Problem is that sometimes a comma is common between two adjacent Managrial position. So I need to include comma when I want to find the positions but I need to exclude it when I want to replace the position with 3! How Can I do that with a regular expression in Python?

Here is the [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-l8u3pzgtTZwggZcp2nc1XurTOMo4RLh/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) can help solve a lot of these sort of problems. Throw some sample text in there along with the regex you currently have and I'll see if I can help you narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks, emsimpson92. I will try it.

Comment: What tool or language you are using? Regex on Google spreadsheets?

Comment: @wp78de, I'm working with python.

Comment: Just add the commas back in? https://regex101.com/r/7creCj/1

Comment: @wp78de, that's great! but now the problem is that how can I replace them with 3? If I include commas, like ,regex, with ,3, then I will have a lot of commas when comma is common between two adjacent results. How can I exclude comma when I want to replace the result with 3? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Python's built-in CSV module instead. Let's not reinvent the wheel here and consider handling CSV as a solved problem.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates how it can be done: The csv module is responsible for [reading and writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) the file with the correct delimiter and quotation char.
re.search is used to search individual cells/columns for your keyword. If `manager` is found, put a 3, otherwise, put the original content and write the row back when done.

```
import csv, sys, re

infile= r'in.csv'
outfile= r'out.csv'
o = open(outfile, 'w', newline='')
csvwri = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

with open(infile, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            newrow = []
            for col in row:
                if re.search("manager", col, re.I):
                    newrow.append("3")
                else:
                    newrow.append(col)
            csvwri.writerow(newrow)
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file {}, line {}: {}'.format(infile, reader.line_num, e))

o.flush()
o.close()
```

Straightforward and clean, I would say.

If you insist on using a regex, here's an improved pattern:

```
[,\s]?([A-Za-z. '\s/()\"]+)?(Manager|manager)([A-Za-z. '\s/()]+)?(?=,)
```

Replace with 3, as shown in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7creCj/2).

However, I believe you are still better off with the csv lib approach.